# Using structs and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to learn how to represent a graph and came across this code, and trying to understand it, so I can implement heaps along with dijkstras algorithm.

I am unfamiliar with this struct referencing:

```
graph->array[i].head = NULL;
```

Is this legit for structs? I didn't see this sort of thing in my C book, quite interesting. is it because the code allocated enough memory for the array in the above line?

```
graph->array = (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList));
```

Part of the code to put things into context. Please help, really trying to understand this struct syntax can't get my head around to why this sort of referencing is possible?

```
  // A C Program to demonstrate adjacency list representation of graphs

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// A structure to represent an adjacency list node
struct AdjListNode
{
    int dest;
    struct AdjListNode* next;
};

// A structure to represent an adjacency list
struct AdjList
{
    struct AdjListNode *head;  // pointer to head node of list
};

// A structure to represent a graph. A graph is an array of adjacency lists.
// Size of array will be V (number of vertices in graph)
struct Graph
{
    int V;
    struct AdjList* array;
};

// A utility function to create a new adjacency list node
struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(int dest)
{
    struct AdjListNode* newNode =
            (struct AdjListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode));
    newNode->dest = dest;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

// A utility function that creates a graph of V vertices
struct Graph* createGraph(int V)
{
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->V = V;

    // Create an array of adjacency lists.  Size of array will be V
    graph->array = (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList));

     // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by making head as NULL
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        graph->array[i].head = NULL;

    return graph;
}
```

Comment: "can't get my head around to why this sort of referencing is possible" - why shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: Because I'm unfamiliar with it :X and can't find any notes online about it, would you care to enlighten me?

Comment: `[]` is array indexing, `.` is struct member access, and `->` is dereference plus struct member access (`a->b` would be the same as `(*a).b`)... and they're just chained together. Since [they all have the same precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the statement would be synonymous with `(((*graph).array)[i]).head = NULL;`, if that helps.

Comment: This is no tutoring site. If you have problems decoding standard (and not too complicated) standard C constructs. you should eitehr consult a different book (the didactics might not suit you) or maybe you just missed the idea about `struct`s and **pointers** (there is no array in the code shown).

Comment: @Siguza: `[]` is the index-operator. It is applied to pointers, never to arrays!

Comment: @Olaf is there a link where I can read about index-operators for pointers? that you could perhaps recommend?

Comment: @Olaf [The final draft of the C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) calls it "the array-subscript operator" (§6.6.9, pg. 107).

Comment: @Siguza: Yes, it is the that operator. But it does not operate on arrays as your comment implies, but on pointers, one of the most missunderstood (yet important) differences.

Answer (score 0):

This example should help you to understand easily.

```
typedef struct ITEM
{
    int num;
} ITEM;

ITEM i;
i.num = 123; // this is what you already know

ITEM *p = &i; // p is pointer to i
p->num = 456; // to change value of struct pointer member, use '->'
// i.num is 456 now

(*p).num = 789; // alternative way
// i.num is 789 now
```

Comment: Sorry, I understand structs, it was just the part where it used [ ] apparently its an index operator for pointers, never came across this before

Comment: @Hyune If you have `malloc` the `int *p` for 10 ints, it is completely valid to do `p[9] = 123;`, as it is the same as `*(p + 9) = 123;`.